# How can I use vitest to test react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, vitest

I want to test form validation and console.log data if every form is valid. I am using react hook form and vitest. The problem I was having was I can't insert onSubmit method in my component because I am not passing it through parent component.
how can i achieve it?
here is my code for the component i want to test.

```
    import { ControllerProps, useForm, SubmitHandler } from "react-hook-form"
import { AddUserFormType } from "../../contracts/campaigns/"
import Button from "../../components/buttons/Button"
import { FormInput } from "../../components/forms"

const AddUserForm = () => {
    const {
        control,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm<AddUserFormType>()
    const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<AddUserFormType> = (data) => console.log(data)

    const myControl = control as unknown as ControllerProps["control"]

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <FormInput
                type="text"
                control={myControl}
                name="firstName"
                label="First Name"
                error={errors.firstName?.message}
                rules={{ required: { value: true, message: "First name is required" } }}
            />
            <FormInput
                type="text"
                control={myControl}
                name="lastName"
                label="Last Name"
                error={errors.lastName?.message}
                rules={{ required: { value: true, message: "Last name is required" } }}
            />
            <FormInput
                type="text"
                control={myControl}
                name="phoneNumber"
                label="Phone Number"
                error={errors.phoneNumber?.message}
                rules={{ required: { value: true, message: "Phone Number" } }}
            />
            <FormInput
                type="email"
                control={myControl}
                name="emailAddress"
                label="Email Address"
                error={errors.emailAddress?.message}
                rules={{ required: { value: true, message: "Email is required" } }}
            />
            <Button title="Submit" type="submit" />
        </form>
    )
}
export default AddUserForm
```